# Transform transulate is disable CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

In my css style of a div componennt the transform transulate id disabled the style so how to enable it to position ?

[SS of problem](https://ibb.co/7VLgppQ)

solution for style in transform

Comment: Post your code in place of a link to an image.

Comment: means full code or just the div style code ?

Comment: Just create a functional snippet that relate your issue in order to help people to help you. Just type ctrl + m then provide a reproducible example.

Comment: after clicking cnrl+m on vs code it shows "tab moves focus" in bottom  so what did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but this may help you to ask questions on SO to get a reproducible example:

Click on the message-field to post your question and then click ctrl + m to open the snippet maker window.
There's also a button above the message field to open this window : just click on the <> icon.

```js
let txt = document.getElementById("text");
txt.innerHTML = "How to ask a question";
```

```css
#text{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:1.6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```